# display the contents of another page inside tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

how am I going to display the external page inside my tabs? I have these four tabs and aiming to call the external pages when it was clicked.

```
 <div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs" role="tabpanel" style="padding-top: 70px;">
            <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
              <li>
                  <a href="#ViewPools.aspx" id="#tab0" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"  >Pool
                </a></li>

                <li>
                 <a href="#tabCategory" id="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >Category
                </a></li>

                <li>
                <a href="#tab2" id="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SLA
                </a></li>

                <li>
                <a href="#tab3" id="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Notification
                </a></li>

            </ul>

            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="ViewPools"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

is there any way I can do this using jquery? thanks

Comment: Yes you can use iframe inside the div and change iframe src attribute acc to anchor href.   <iframe src="" id="frpage"/>

Comment: the page I am going to call has jquery, I guess iframe is only for displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#container {
        width: 388px;
        height: 280px;
        border: 0px solid #000;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
}

#container iframe {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 700px;
        margin-left: -514px;
        margin-top: -279px;
        border: 0 solid;
}
-->
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <iframe
        src="http://stackoverflow.com/"
        scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div> 
</body>
```

You can access any number of pages by creating multiple iframes, replace your desired webpage with src I used in code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link which is  get useful to you , click on 'category'.

[`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/965/)